# Review seems to need to be refreshed

Tags: bug, review

Whenever I get the "there are no more items to review in this queue" (or "you've performed your limit for this queue") and click on Review at the top left to go back to the main Review page, I seem to need to click it again to actually see updated results.

That is, it most often still displays non-zero numbers for the queue I've just cleared (and if I do click on them again they immediately show "no more items"), but they're zeroed on a refresh.

I'm guessing this is actually some sort of caching bug.

Comment: @rene It may be a related answer, but I'm definitely see an update on refresh, whereas for that question it was _not_ corrected by refreshing.

Comment: OK, but I guess the answer is the same. You now might hit a different server behind the loadbalancer that serves you different results (I'm not saying correct results).